# Python: extract strings between defined characters and store into a disctionary with lists

Tags: python

I have a folder defined as

> /home/folder

This folder has lots of files in it, something like:

```
folder
├── this.py
├── that
└── something
```

Inside these files there is a lot of text out of which there are lines stored in between 6 # characters like this:

```
cat this.py

    ###### This is what I'm looking for ######
    ###### This is the second line that I'm looking for ######
```

What I want to do is to extract the text from between these 6 # and store them into a dictionary of arrays that should have the below structure:

```
my_list = {file1: [string1, string2, string3], file2: [string1, string2, string3]}
```

Making an example out of the above:

```
my_list = {'this.py': ['This is what I'm looking for', 'This is the second line that I'm looking for'}
```

So I need the file names without the full path and the corresponding strings without the 6 #. Also, I want to store only the files that have a valid string. Those that don't comply shouldn't be in the dictionary at all.

I've used this function to traverse the directory but I'm not sure how to approach the problem further ahead:

```
def get_directory_structure(rootdir):
    """
    Creates a nested dictionary that represents the folder structure of rootdir
    """
    dir = {}
    rootdir = rootdir.rstrip(os.sep)
    start = rootdir.rfind(os.sep) + 1
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        folders = path[start:].split(os.sep)
        subdir = dict.fromkeys(files)
        parent = reduce(dict.get, folders[:-1], dir)
        parent[folders[-1]] = subdir
    return dir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one level of directory (no subdirectories to traverse), You may try this:

```
import os

def extract(name):
    with open(name, "rt") as f:
        a = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip("\r\n")
            if line.startswith("###### ") and line.endswith(" ######"):
                a.append(line[7:-7])
        return a

def create_dict(path):
    h = {}
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        a = extract(os.path.join(path, name))
        if a:
            h[name] = a
    return h
```

If there are subdirectories to traverse, you may use instead of `create_dict`:

```
def create_dict_walk(path):
    h = {}
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            a = extract(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            if a:
                h[filename] = a
    return h
```

Note, however, that you may need some checks if your files have an unusual encoding, or if only some files need to be checked (according to extension, date, or whatever). Also, here, the function will only use the filename, and there may be duplicates in different subdirectories.

The functions also store a list only when there are actually some # lines. Just remove the test if you want an empty list instead when there is none.

Comment: Thanks man. However, what if I want it to include only the file names that comply with the rule? For example if there is a file that doesn't contain any strings between 6 # I wouldn't want the name included in the dictionary.

Comment: @Sorin-MihaiOprea I updated `create_dict` to add a test. Now both functions only store a list if it's not empty.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks. :)